# select command does not work in SQL*Plus but does in APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I'm currently learning this for my work from a book (German book named "Oracle Express Edition" from author Stefan Heitsiek from 2012) that has been given to me. So far I have done everything like it is in the book, but it won't work when I try it.

The problem is as following:
I have a fresh install of ORACLE Database XE 11.2 and used the existing Workspace 'HR' as stated in the book. 
I now have to put in the following command into SQL*Plus `select * from regions;` The book states that I have to log in into the "HR" Account in SQL*Plus with `connect hr/password` though when I try that it says

```
SQL> connect hr/password
ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked
```

But when I look into "Administration" -> "Manage Users and Groups" in ORACLE APEX it says right there that the user "HR" is not Locked. That is my first problem.

The second problem, as stated in the title is, if I put in the command `select * from regions;` into my SQL*Plus Window (if logged in as sysdba since HR is not working) there comes an error stating

```
SQL> select * from regions;
select * from regions
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Even though the table is clearly there when I check it in the "SQL Workshop" -> "Object Browser".

But when I put in the same command in the ORACLE APEX "SQL Workshop" -> "SQL Commands" window, I do get the result.

Comment: SQL Server <> Oracle; they are 2 very different RDBMS.

Comment: `select * from HR.regions;` -- from sys account to access HR schema object

Comment: To unlock HR user execute this command from sys account: `ALTER USER HR IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;`

Comment: "Administration" -> "Manage Users and Groups" is for APEX user accounts, these have no connection with database schemas.